# PhpSpreadsheet setCellValue to "=Image(URL)" becomes "=@Image(URL)" which is unrecognized be excel (#NAME)

Tags: phpspreadsheet

In a basic Office 365 Excel spreadsheet, I can enter '=Image("url-to-an-image")' and the image shows in the cell. (documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5)

Now in PhpSpreadsheet if I use:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$url = "URL-to-image-file";
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue("A1", "=Image(\"$url\")");

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('test.xlsx');
```

The resulting text/formula in cell A1 of text.xlsx is:
=@Image("URL-to-image-file") and the cell shows #NAME.  If, from within excel I remove the '@' then the expected image shows.

I have also tried:

```
setCellValueExplicit("A1", "=Image(\"$url\")", \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
```

which gives the same result

I also tried some code for array formulas, that did not work either.

Edit: Some additional info:
I see that if, in Excel, I enter "=@Image('URL')" the image is displayed as expected.  I also see that if created by PhpSpreadsheet, and then opened in Excel it shows #NAME.  But if in Excel I edit the cell and just hit  with no change to the formula, the image shows.

How I can create this formula and when opened in excel the image is retrieved and shown?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.